# is adcolony 2.0.1.33 compatible with ios7?

Tags: ios, sdk, ads, ios7, xcode5

I know that AdColony has a new sdk2.2 which was tested on ios7.
However, our app is currently using 2.0.1.33 which is the sdk that doesn't use the udid. Basically, it's the sdk prior to 2.2
What will happen if i don't upgrade my sdk2.2? Will it still be compatible with ios7? Will my app experience problems?
I'm not really sure about the consequences of not updating. But right now when i'm testing on an ios7 device and i'm still able to get ads from AdColony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We knew that not everyone would be able to update their apps the minute that iOS7 became available, so we have throughly tested the 2.0.1.33 release with iOS 7 and it is fully compatible.

However, you should still plan to update to our newest SDK, 2.2, as it is more advanced than 2.0.1.33.  Please let us know if we can help with anything by emailing support@adcolony.com.

-AdColony Support

Comment: Thank you. About sdk 2.2, i can't seem to make it work. I followed your walkthrough and my AdColony gets disabled due to NSData error. Do you know what could cause this?